# Puppet facter slow for some network facts

Tags: ruby, performance, puppet, vagrant, facter

I'm learning about [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) and [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/puppet-enterprise/).
When I use the vagrant lucid32 (Ubuntu 10.04), puppet seems very slow.
I've fixed the fqdn problem [(question 7780322)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780322/puppet-facter-could-not-retrieve-fact-fqdn-how-to-fix-or-circumvent) but it's still very slow.

I've traced (part of) the problem to facter. Asking for ipaddress is very quick, but ipaddress_eth0 takes 20 seconds:

```
root@a:/# time facter ipaddress
10.0.2.15

real    0m0.031s
user    0m0.024s
sys     0m0.004s
root@a:/# time facter ipaddress_eth0
10.0.2.15

real    0m20.126s
user    0m0.080s
sys     0m0.020s
root@a:/#
```

Looking for ipaddress_lo is also slow.

Can anyone help me with a solution or a suggestion for how to debug this? I'm new to Ruby, but willing to learn.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that `arp -a` runs very slowly.

```
vagrant@lucid32:~$ time arp -a
? (10.0.2.3) at 52:54:00:12:35:03 [ether] on eth0
? (10.0.2.2) at 52:54:00:12:35:02 [ether] on eth0

real    0m20.022s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
vagrant@lucid32:~$
```

I assume that this is a problem with some combination of virtualbox (4.1.12_77245), host-only networking, ubuntu 10.04, and windows 7 host OS.

As a workaround, assuming that I can learn a bit about puppet without it knowing my mac addresses, I replaced line 7 of `/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/facter-1.6.0/lib/facter/arp.rb` as follows:

```
require 'facter/util/ip'

Facter.add(:arp) do
  confine :kernel => :linux
  setcode do
    ### output = Facter::Util::Resolution.exec('arp -a') # disable for slow arp
    output = "" ### return a blank, rather than the real (but slow) arp
    if not output.nil?
      arp = ""
      output.each_line do |s|
        if s =~ /^\S+\s\S+\s\S+\s(\S+)\s\S+\s\S+\s\S+$/
          arp = $1.downcase
          break # stops on the first match
        end
      end
    end
    "fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff" == arp ? arp : nil
  end
end

Facter::Util::IP.get_interfaces.each do |interface|
  Facter.add("arp_" + Facter::Util::IP.alphafy(interface)) do
    confine :kernel => :linux
    setcode do
      arp = Facter::Util::IP.get_arp_value(interface)
      "fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff" == arp ? arp : nil
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks like it's the name lookup perhaps taking a long time.  Try changing the command to "arp -an"?  If that's the case, ideally you should fix your DNS resolver for the reverse lookups, but it may also be worth filing a Puppet bug to have -n added.

Answer (score 1):

I just defined the unknown hosts(?) in 
/etc/hosts:

```
10.0.2.3 computer1
10.0.2.2 computer2
```

After this, the arp -a was very quick and hence improved the response of facter -p in-turn improved the performance of puppet agent --test